# How do I execute some code in a superclass after all the subclasses have been constructed?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop

Is there a way to do this in C#? I know that the subclass will call the superclass constructor before calling its own constructor, but what If I have some code on the superclass that should only be executed after all the subclasses constructors have been called?

Comment: Do you have a specific usage example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to go for a 2 phase construct and initialize. So you construct the instances and then call an initialize method which invoked the base class Initialize in the appropriate order

```
class MyBase
{
  // Only if need to do some core initialization
  public MyBase()
  {
  }

  public virtual Initialize()
  {
    // do some initialization stuff here
  }
}

class MyDerived : MyBase
{
  // Only if need to do some core initialization
  public MyDerived()
  {
  }

  public override Initialize()
  {
    // do some initialization stuff here

    // Call the base class initialization function
    base.Initialize();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you go for two-pass create/initialize, I would advise using a factory method or Asbtract Factory to ensure that initialization semantics are not spread all over the code.

Comment: Ok, that is not exactly what I meant but it kinda helps me solve the problem, ty.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following, but it is risky (see my Edit below):

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected virtual void Initialize()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // do child stuff
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As suggested in Terrence's comment below, this is a risky approach because `Initialize()` will be executed before `Child`'s constructor is executed. If there are any fields initialized in `Child`'s constructor, they won't be ready if they are used by `Initialize()`. This could cause confusing bugs.

A simple solution would be to give up on the Parent calling `Initialize()` and instead have the child classes call `Initialize()`. As others have suggested, another option would be to use the abstract factory pattern.

Here is a simple solution that uses a static factory method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Child.Create(() => new Child(5));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class Parent
{
    protected virtual void Initialize()
    {
        Console.Write(" is the number.");
    }

    public static TChild Create<TChild>(Func<TChild> childGetter)
        where TChild : Parent
    {
        var child = childGetter();
        child.Initialize();
        return child;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    private int _number;

    public Child(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Console.Write(_number.ToString());
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: This violates the recommendation against calling virtual methods from a constructor.  This method can lead to difficult to track down bugs.

See: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottwil/archive/2005/01/14/353177.aspx
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308061/virtualization-in-super-class-constructor

Answer (score 2):

**There is nothing built into the C# language that lets you do this.  However, using a creation pattern could support it.**  For example, the [Abstract Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx) pattern might be helpful here.  The base factory would ensure that a method is called on the newly created base class once it has been instantiated as the concrete child type.

Comment: Do you know if Castle Windsor has something like that?

Comment: This is really more the domain of an AOP tool such as PostSharp (which you've now reminded me should've been included in my answer), but it might be possible to have Windsor do it.  Never tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A : B
{
   public A() : base()
   {
      base.doSomething();
   }
}

class B : C
{
   public B() : base()
   {

   }

   public void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
}

class C
{
   public C() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Execution Order should be:

1. C::ctor()
2. B::ctor()
3. A::ctor()
4. B::doSomething()

Comment: As I said, the method should be executed in the superclass, not in the subclass, you are just calling the superclass method in the subclass.

Comment: I suspect the OP is looking for a solution where the base class can ensure that some initialization runs after the type is fully instantiated. Otherwise, each derived class author must make sure to call the necessary initialization logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean - can't you just call the code in the super class at the end of our last subclass constructor? Alternatively you could call it directly after instantiation.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubSub obj = new SubSub();                
            //obj.DoStuff();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Super
    {
        public Super()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructing Super");
        }
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doin' stuff");
        }
    }

    class Sub : Super
    {
        public Sub()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructing Sub");
        }
    }

    class SubSub : Sub
    {
        public SubSub()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructing SubSub");
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
```

This will output:

```
Constructing Super 
Constructing Sub
Constructing SubSub 
Doin' stuff
```

Comment: What I mean is that the code could be executed after complete construction of the object in the superclass, the subclass shouldnt know about it.